# javascript/css popup div in php file

Tags: javascript, php, html, css, popup

I followed this guide for creating a popup div on my front page http://webdesignandsuch.com/how-to-create-a-popup-with-css-and-javascript/

The thing is im not so familiar with coding and i want to put the code in my php file(wordpress site here). I don't know if i can make it work without the  tag since my file isnt html so i tried to put pure javascript in it. The css code from the website is in the css style file of my wordpress site and of course the js file is in the folder as well! This is where i got stuck :

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="css-pop.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
function popup() {
document.getElementById("popUpDiv").style.display = "block";
}
window.onload=function popup();
</script>

<div id="blanket" style="display:none"></div>
<div id="popUpDiv" style="display:none"></div>
```

Can someone tell me the right code so i can get it working? Thanks!

Comment: I'm guessing you may also be using `window.onload` within your css-pop.js file. `window.onload` only supports one event of that type, and every time you use it, it will use the most recent occurrence of the event. In your case, if you have `window.onload` in css-pop.js, it will not work. I suggest using jquery `$(document).ready(function(){//code here});` or take a look here on how to modify `window.onload` http://www.htmlgoodies.com/beyond/javascript/article.php/3724571/Using-Multiple-JavaScript-Onload-Functions.htm

Answer (score 2):

Try to replace

```
window.onload=function popup();
```

with

```
window.onload=popup; // or window.onload = function(){ popup(); };
```

You can read more at http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_htmldom_events.asp

Answer (score 0):

```
function popup() {
    document.getElementById("popUpDiv").style.display = "block";
}
window.onload = function() {
    popup();
}
```

try this.it will work ..

Answer (score 0):

First of all, the best thing to do is to create a modal pop up, theorically, it's a hidden div that you show on an event. It will be a simple div that you can implement with whatever you want. I can imagine that you want  a pop up centered in the document. To do that, create a div just after the body tag, and add to it a little bit of css, position absolute to center the pop up about the document and add properties top and left, z-index to show the pup-up over everything else on the page, the value must be the biggest z-index of the stylesheet. Then, the javascript code to show the pop-up on the onload event:

```
<html>
 <head>
   <title>Title of the document</title>
 </head>
<body>

<div id="popUp" style="display:none;z-index:10;position:absolute;top:50%;left:50%;">
 //Put the pop up content here
</div>

 //Your other elements

<script type="text/javascript">
window.onload = function (){showPopup();};
function showPopup()
{
    document.getElementById("popUp").style.display = "block";
}
</script>
</body>
```